# After upgrade from 22.04 to 23.04, kernels > 5.17 freeze a boot

Tags: boot, kernel

Any of the newer kernels > 5.17 (running Linux galactica 5.17.5-051705-generic here) all freeze during boot up, just after loading initrd, without printing anything -- even though I'm setting loglevel=7 and --verbose (i saw someone recommend that).

Is there anything I can do to make it print out something that will hint on what is going on ? Or even better, any ideas on what could be happening ?

Thanks!

Configuration: Intel 12900k, nvidia 2080ti., nvme hd (boot) + a couple of old ssd drives mounted.

ps: And with kernel 5.17.5 the snap apps all don't receive any keyboard input -- not sure why, but Firefox, the Ubuntu Software itself and other snap installed programs don't work. Same have been reported in other questions.

============

**Update 1:**

After a couple of changes, the kernel situation reversed, 6.2.0 kernel is booting, and 5.17.5 freezes. The changes were:

(1) I changed /etc/default/grub:

GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text nosplash debug loglevel=7 apic=verbose --verbose"

(the change to the line above was only adding "text" parameter)

(2) I installed `ubuntu-budgie-desktop`

Not sure what of the two did the trick though.

Alas, the sysiphus-like upgrade is not over yet. Now I boot on 6.2.0, but Xorg doesn't work, and it doesn't even show a terminal (control+alt F? keys dont' change console).

I can ssh to the machine, and also booting it in recovery mode works, but it boots in 1024x768, it doesn't recognize the video card (nvidia 2080ti). The drivers are still there though -- but they are the 530 ones, and 23.04 only seems to support nvidia 525, so I'll downgrade next.

============

**Update 2:**

After purging all packages with "nvidia" in their name, and reinstallin, replacing 530 by 525, update-initramfs and update-grub ...

Now both kernels (5.17.5 and 6.2.0) freeze immediately after loading initial ramdisk. No messages printed in the console, no indications of it could be.

Question, could this be related to the "initrd" files being located in an nvme drive, and maybe the kernel doesn't know how to read it if, for intance, the drive is bigger than a certain size and the file is somehow located above that limit? -- there had been issues like that in old partition types in Linux.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has no upgrade option to move to 23.04; so are you using Ubuntu? (*and details of your 'upgrade' maybe helpful). The kernel `5.17.5-051705-generic` is also only a *testing* kernel and not a *supported* Ubuntu kernel, so are you using Ubuntu?  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS's GA kernel is still 5.15, HWE currently 5.19 & -edge will soon be 6.2 so 5.17?

Comment: I am also not sure where kernel 5.17 comes from. Ubuntu 23.04 should have kernel 6.2 with better support for newer hardware.

Comment: In the same day I upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10 and then to 23.04.

From the 22.04 one of the 5.17 kernels was working so I installed manually the latest test kernel from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.15/.  Btw I previously also had a 5.15 kernel installed, but it was not working in 23.04 ... I assumed it was something else, I'm not sure.

Comment: You might want to see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469482/after-upgrade-from-22-04-to-23-04-kernels-5-17-freeze-a-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I still dont' understand how/why but I seem to have solved it by:

(1) I changed /etc/default/grub:

GRUB_TERMINAL=console GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text nosplash debug loglevel=7 apic=verbose --verbose"

(the change to the line above was only adding "text" parameter)

(2) I installed ubuntu-budgie-desktop

(3) Purged any nvidia package

(4) Installed the nouveau XOrg package.

Rebooted

(4) Installed nvidia drivers using the UI "Software Updater" tool (in settings)

Things are booting normally in kernel 6.2.0 now (but not in 5.17 kernel), and things look normal so far.

Now some stuff I need to re-install (nvidia support for dockers for instance). But I'll mark this as resolved for now.